# What are Clojure Intrinsics

Tags: clojure, compiler-construction, clojure-java-interop

Browsing the Clojure source code I came across an [`Intrinsics.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Intrinsics.java) file. It looks like it is a mapping of some clojure runtime functions to JVM opcodes.

However, I am not sure where they get applied. The following code

```
(def ^:const pi 3.141592)
(defn circumference [^double r] (* r 2.0 pi))
```

compiles to

```
public static java.lang.Object invokeStatic(double r);
 0  dload_0 [r]
 1  ldc2_w <Double 2.0> [14]
 4  dmul
 5  ldc2_w <Double 3.141592> [16]
 8  invokestatic clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply(double, double) : double [23]
11  invokestatic java.lang.Double.valueOf(double) : java.lang.Double [29]
14  areturn
```

and I see that `clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply(double, double) : double` did not get replaced to `DMUL`.

How exactly are intrinsics used? Thank you.

Comment: This may be a better question for the Clojure email list:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently intrinsics are only used where the expression being compiled is meant to remain unboxed. Thus the `(* r 2.0)` multiplication in your example does receive the intrinsic treatment (resulting in the one `dmul` in your example `invokeStatic`), but the `(* #<result of (* r 2.0)> 3.141592)` multiplication does not.

You can get the `clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply(double, double) : double` intrinsic to be applied to the multiplication by `r` as well by ensuring that the return type is `double` as well.

For example this:

```
(def ^:const pi 3.141592)
(defn circumference ^double [^double r] (* r 2.0 pi))
```

compiles to the following:

```
public static double invokeStatic(double r);
   0  dload_0 [r]
   1  ldc2_w <Double 2.0> [14]
   4  dmul
   5  ldc2_w <Double 3.141592> [16]
   8  dmul
   9  dreturn
```